# Is Docker-ized dev envoirment good for maintaining legacy software?

Tags: docker, legacy

Let's say I have old, unmaintained application that lives on a VPS (i.e. Symfony 3 PHP app that relies on PHP 5).

If some changes are needed I have to clone this app to my desktop, build it, change and re-deploy. As time goes, recreating desktop dev environment gets harder - in this example I can't simply build the app as I use PHP7 in my CLI that breaks building process.

I tried to dockerize the app, so I added Ubuntu 18 to my docker-compose file... and it doesn't work as latest Ubuntu that has PHP5 support is 14.04. 14.04 is also the oldest (official) version available on DockerHub. But will it be still available in 3 years? If not, Docker won't build a container.

So, my question is: **is Docker a right tool to solve described problem** at all?
If so, should I backup docker images described that my build relies on?
If not, beside proper maintenance, what tool is better?

Comment: Yes it the best thing to use for such use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can install PHP5 in newer ubuntu versions, but it means adding an external repository.

You could also create your own docker image, containing only the libraries you want. If so, I'd advise to try and use alpine as a base image. There is a bit of a learning curve to adapt, but once you do it you'll have a small image tailored to your needs.

Given that containers allow you to isolate processus and conf with minimal footprint compared to a VM, I think it is the best option. Tailoring and maintaining your own image is not that expensive in terms of maintenance if you document it correctly, and it will allow you to always have a system 'maintaining' all your precise requirements.

Comment: If the external repository won't be available or it won't have the version I precisely ask building won't work. Relying on external repos doesn't seem to be safe on longer term.

Comment: I agree. That's why I recommend using alpine and building your own image.